# How to create "Write" clone of a production RDS Aurora instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a production DB that is on RDS Aurora MySQL. I would like to create a "staging" version of it, so I need a complete duplicate/clone of the production version.

Most importantly I need the staging version to have write access to the new instance.

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a '"write" clone'?  [Clones are writable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html).

Comment: The clone should have write permissions to itself, not just read permission

Comment: A clone (read/write) is not a replica (read only).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Review [Cloning Databases in an Aurora DB Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html) in the RDS User Guide.

Clones are not the same thing as replicas.  A replica, in Aurora, has read-only access to the same data store allowing you to spread out your read workload across multiple instances... but a clone is a readable/writable moment-in-time fork of your original database.  Any changes after the clone is created don't change the data on the original database instances (or on any other clones, and up to 15 independent clones are currently supported).

You can also create a new Aurora cluster from a snapshot of your production database, but a clone is probably the preferred solution for two reasons: it's faster to create a clone... but perhaps more importantly, clones use copy-on-write, so until you change the data on either the clone or the master it was cloned from, they share common storage space in the Aurora Cluster Volume that stores the data -- so you're only paying once for storage of the data that never gets changed.  How this works is explained, with diagrams, in the RDS User Guide at the link, above.

Answer (score 0):

You can take Backup ( Database snapshot ) on prod and restore the backup into new RDS Aurora  servers ( during RDS Aurora instance creation) . It is simple GUI interface in AWS. You can change your permission after database has been restored into stage.

Comment: AWS Aurora has a "Clone" feature which is actually much much faster than the method outlined in this answer.